# Как добавить значение из переменной в объект data для выполнения ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, ajax

друзья!
Для передачи в ajax запрос собираю данные из формы методом serializeArray. Как можно добавить значение из переменной, не связанной с формой, в data ajax запроса?
И еще, как можно посмотреть что лежит в data? Если с помощью , то выводит только [object Object].
Благодарю заранее!

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Вы не сможете просмотреть данные формы через `alert()` если использовали `serializeArray()`, в таком случае нужно вывести данные в консоль браузера через команду `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас всё хорошо с передачей данных формы в аяксе, то вы можете добавить переменную в конец массива и также передать его как и раньше:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#example', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // отключаем стандартное поведение отправки формы
  var form_data = $(this).serializeArray(); // формируем массив данных формы
  form_data[form_data.length] = { // добавляем последний элемент как объект с именем и значением
    'name': 'user_id',
    'value': '1'
  }
  console.log(form_data); // смотрим что теперь у нас лежит в массиве
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="example">
  ФИО&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
  Телефон&nbsp;<input type="number" name="phone" /><br/>
  Адрес&nbsp;<input type="text" name="address" /><br/>
  
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button
</form>
```